# IntelliJ: removing commands for CVS, Mercurial, Subversion, etc

Tags: git, intellij-idea, version-control

I'm exclusively using git/github.  Is there a way to remove all command referernces/options that refer to non-git VCS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Settings (Ctrl+Alt+S in the default keymap) > Plugins, disable the respective plugins (CVS Integration, Subversion Integration, hg4idea, etc.):

[image]

On Mac: IntelliJ / Preferences, `Command-,`.

Comment: Perfect.  I added a note that "settings" = Mac "preferences".